# pip is looking for multiple version of <library> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements

Tags: python, pip

While installing a package, I am constantly getting a message like

```
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Downloading scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.1 MB 55 kB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.1 MB 1.6 MB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.3.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.2 MB 23 kB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.3.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.2 MB 63.6 MB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.2 MB 1.6 MB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.3.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 25.2 MB 1.8 MB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.2.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.8 MB 49 kB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.2.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.8 MB 2.0 MB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.8 MB 1.8 MB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.6 MB 76 kB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (31.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 31.2 MB 120 kB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.0.1.tar.gz (15.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.5 MB 70 kB/s 
  Downloading scipy-1.0.0.tar.gz (15.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.2 MB 46 kB/s 
  ...
```

And this goes on.. which takes lot of time.

How can I help pip resolve the dependencies and complete the install faster?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Did you just post a question to then answer it...????

Comment: @SomeSimpleton Self answering is actually encouraged. It's in the spirit of this being Q&A site. See also [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) from the help center.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Dang didn't know that, that's cool just for knowledge storage. You learn something new every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just update your pip.

This worked for me. and it took 2 days for me to figure it out

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
```

Hope this will help you all.

Comment: For future readers, this works if you are using a version of pip between v20.3 (when backtracking was added) and v22 (when the backtracker received a major update)